# Hibernate createSQLQuery. How to get boolean

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, boolean, biginteger

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM master.invoices WHERE currency_id = 17879)").list()
```

gives me BigInteger.
How can I get boolean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how it works.

```
Boolean.valueOf((List<String>) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT IF
(SELECT 1 FROM master.invoices WHERE currency_id = 17879)
, 'true', 'false')").list());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this accordingly dude

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
SELECT * 
FROM 
master.invoices
WHERE currency_id = 17879
)
THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
```

Comment: this code gives me an error. `.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END' at line 1`